# wso2 api manager does not support URL pattern demo/*.action

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I published my API at WSO2 API Publisher with url pattern 
`demo/test.action` which will return a json object.

From API Store, when I 'try it out' from API console, it gives response code 200 which means it worked successfully. 
But from the 'Response Body' it gives me,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    
    <title>WSO2 API Manager</title>
    
    <link href="../admin/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>

    <link href="../styles/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link href="../dialog/css/jqueryui/jqueryui-themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          media="all"/>
    <link href="../dialog/css/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../admin/css/carbonFormStyles.css">
    <!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link href="../dialog/css/dialog-ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>        
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link href="../dialog/css/dialog-ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="icon" href="../admin/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../admin/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dialog/js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/WSRequest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/cookies.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../admin/js/customControls.js"></script>
</head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  if(getCookie('region1_configure_menu') == null){
  setCookie('region1_configure_menu', 'none');
}
if(getCookie('region3_registry_menu') == null){
  setCookie('region3_registry_menu', 'none');
}
if(getCookie('region4_monitor_menu') == null){
  setCookie('region4_monitor_menu', 'none');
}
if(getCookie('region5_tools_menu') == null){
  setCookie('region5_tools_menu', 'none');
}

  </script>
  
<body>
<noscript>
<div class="something-wrong">
 <div class="title">JavaScript is disabled on your browser</div>
 <div class="content">Please enable JavaScript or upgrade to a JavaScript-capable browser to use WSO2 Products.</div>
</div>
</noscript>
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<div class="something-wrong">
 <div class="title">Did you know that your Internet Explorer is out of date?</div>
 <div class="content">To get the best possible experience using our website we recommend that you upgrade to a newer version.</div>
</div>
<![endif]-->

<div id="dcontainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dialog/js/dialog.js"></script>

<!-- JS imports for collapsible menu -->
<script src="../yui/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../yui/build/animation/animation-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../admin/js/template.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../yui/build/yahoo/yahoo-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../yui/build/selector/selector-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<table id="main-table" border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="header" colspan="3">









<!--[IF IE 7]>
 <style>
  div#header-div div.right-links{
   position:absolute;
  }
 </style>
<![endif]-->


    <div id="header-div">
        <div class="right-logo">Management Console</div>
        <div class="left-logo">
            <a href="../admin/index.jsp" class="header-home"><img src="../admin/images/1px.gif" width="300px" height="32px"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-ad">
            




        </div>
        <div class="header-links">
  <div class="right-links">            
   <ul>
                  
                  <li class="right">
                      <a href="../admin/login.jsp">Sign-in</a>
                  </li>
                  
                  <li class="middle">|</li>
                  <li class="middle">
                      <a target="_blank" href="https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/WSO2+API+Manager+Documentation">Docs</a>
                  </li>
    <li class="middle">|</li>
    
                  <li class="left">
                      <a target="_blank" href="../product/about.html">About</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
  </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="vertical-menu-container" id="vertical-menu-container" style="display:none;">
            <div id="menu-panel-button0"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button1" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button2" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button3" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button4" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button5" class="menu-panel-buttons"></div>
            <div id="menu-panel-button_dummy" style="display:none"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="menu-panel" valign="top">
            <table id="menu-table" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td id="region1">








        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"><li><a href="../admin/index.jsp" class="menu-home">Home</a></li><li id="region1_manage_menu" class="menu-header"  onclick="mainMenuCollapse(this.childNodes[0])" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="../admin/images/up-arrow.gif" class="mMenuHeaders" id="region1_manage_menu"/>Manage</li><li class="normal"><ul class="sub"></ul></li> </ul></div>


</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="region2">



        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"> </ul></div>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="region3">



        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"> </ul></div>

</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="region4">



        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"> </ul></div>

</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="region5">



        <div id="menu"> <ul class="main"> </ul></div>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="../admin/images/1px.gif" width="225px" height="1px"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td id="middle-content">
            <table id="content-table" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td id="page-header-links">





 <table class="page-header-links-table" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <td class="breadcrumbs">
   <table class="breadcrumb-table" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>         
        <td>
         <div id="breadcrumb-div"></div>
                    </td>
    </tr>

   </table>
   </td>

   <td class="page-header-help"><a href="./docs/userguide.html"
    target="_blank">Help</a></td>

  </tr>
 </table>
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="body">
                        <img src="../admin/images/1px.gif" width="735px" height="1px"/>
                        













<script type="text/javascript">
    var msgId;
    
    msgId = 'MSG14563839263210.8448934992899123';
    
</script>









     <script type="text/javascript">

        function doValidation() {
            var reason = "";

            var userNameEmpty = isEmpty("username");
            var passwordEmpty = isEmpty("password");

            if (userNameEmpty || passwordEmpty) {
                CARBON.showWarningDialog('Please enter a valid user name and a password.');
                document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

    </script>

    
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function getSafeText(text){
      text = text.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
      return text.replace(/>/g,'&gt');
     }
    
        function checkInputs(){
         var loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
         var backendUrl = document.getElementById("txtbackendURL");
         var username = document.getElementById("txtUserName");
         
         backendUrl.value = getSafeText(backendUrl.value);
         username.value = getSafeText(username.value);
         loginForm.submit();
        }
    </script>
    <div id="middle">
        <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="features">
                        <table cellspacing="0">
                            <tr class="feature feature-top">
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/WSO2+API+Manager+Documentation"><img src="../admin/images/user-guide.gif"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3><a target="_blank" href="https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/WSO2+API+Manager+Documentation">User Guide</a></h3>

                                    <p>WSO2 Carbon user guide.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="feature">
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="http://wso2.org/forum/187"><img
                                            src="../admin/images/forum.gif"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3><a target="_blank" href="http://wso2.org/forum/187">Forum</a>
                                    </h3>

                                    <p>The interactive message board for sharing information, questions and comments about WSO2 products.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="feature">
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank"
                                       href="https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER"><img
                                            src="../admin/images/issue-tracker.gif"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3><a target="_blank"
                                           href="https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER">
                                        Issue Tracker</a></h3>

                                    <p>Users are encouraged to report issues & suggest improvements using the JIRA issue tracker. In addition, users can observe the status of the reported issues in progress.</p>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="feature">
                                <td>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="http://wso2.org/mail"><img
                                            src="../admin/images/mailing-list.gif"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h3><a target="_blank" href="http://wso2.org/mail">
                                        Mailing Lists</a></h3>

                                    <p>Report issues, provide feedback & get help from our mailing lists.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td width="20%">
                    <div id="loginbox">
                        <h2>Sign-in</h2>

                        <form action='../admin/login_action.jsp' method="POST" onsubmit="return doValidation();" target="_self" onsubmit="checkInputs()">
                            <table>
                                 
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="txtUserName">Username</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="username"
                                               class="user" tabindex="1"  autocomplete="off" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="txtPassword">Password</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="password"
                                               class="password" tabindex="2"  autocomplete="off"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                     <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" 
                                            value="rememberMe" tabindex="3"/>
                                        <label for="txtRememberMe">Remember Me</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Sign-in"
                                               class="button" tabindex="3"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                        <br/>
               <a target="_blank" href="../docs/signin_userguide.html" tabindex="4">
                            Sign-in Help
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init(loginStatus) {
            // intialize the code and call to the back end
            /*wso2.wsf.Util.initURLs();*/
            /*Initialize the XSLT cache*/
            /*wso2.wsf.XSLTHelper.init();*/

            if (loginStatus == 'true') {
            } else if (loginStatus == 'null') {
            } else if (loginStatus == 'false') {
                wso2.wsf.Util.alertWarning("Login failed. Please recheck the user name and password and try again")
            } 
        }
        document.getElementById('txtUserName').focus();
    </script>



                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="footer" colspan="3">

<div id="footer-div">
 <div class="footer-content">
  <div class="copyright">
      &copy; 2005 - 2014 WSO2 Inc. All Rights Reserved.
  </div>
  <!--div class="poweredby">
  </div-->
 </div>
</div>
                        
</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/')()){
    document.documentElement.className+=' ie10';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

which is actually the HTML page of wso2 carbon server.

Does wso2 apim support this kind of pattern??

Comment: You can't publish application on API Manager, You can publish an API there. And, you have to check the backend response is same above. If your backend response is same as your API Manager's API response, then it's fine

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan thank you for your response. Just updated my question and I did publish my API not application on API Manager. And when I tried to access my backend server directly i.e. http://myServerIp/demo/*.action it gave me the correct response (a Json String). But if I want to access through WSO2 it's just not working :(